# Red lines in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

[image]

How can I remove the red lines in Netbeans, I've tried to use another dictionary but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a behaviour caused by NetBeans Spellchecker. Pressing Tools > Options > Editor > Spellchecker you can mark/unmark what type of files you want to check spell for. By default the spellchecker is on for html files, so  unmark HTML/XHTML there - to disable spellchecking for files of these types.